# Unable to resolve "@Given" error on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

I am trying to learn cucumber. i have encountered this issue where @Given annotation is not resolved in eclipse. its showing as error "Given cannot be resolved to a type". i have added the required jars in maven as dependencies but still i am unable to resolve the issue. Kindly please help.

I tried changing the jar file dependencies but still same issue.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>FreeCrmBDDFramework</groupId>
  <artifactId>FreeCrmBDDFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FreeCrmBDDFramework</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

it should either show me suggestions on eclipse or should not show as error if i have written correct line manually but its still showing same issue.

Comment: Do you have m2e installed? Is the project set up to use the `pom.xml` for all of its dependencies?

Comment: Note that you are using very old Cucumber dependencies. Please check the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/) for information on which dependencies you need and the (most) recent version.